# Probability of being late on at least one day

Tags: probability

Peter travels to work either by bus or bike

The probability that peter will travel to work by bus is 0.7
Whenever he travel by bus the the probability that he is late is 0.1

Whenever he travels by bike the probability that he is late is 0.05

He will travel to work on Monday and Tuesday .

Find the probability that he is late on at least one of these days .

My turn :

P(late on one day) = $0.7 \times 0.1 + 0.3 \times 0.05) = 0.085 $
So
P(not late on one day) = $1-0.085 = 0.915$

P(late at least one) = 1-p(not late , not late )

= $1- 0.915 \times 0.915 = 0.162775 $

Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.